# iPad HTML5 Splash Screen sizes

Tags: html

Can anyone help me out to get the exact size for IPAD for displaying the splash screen in both landscape and portrait mode.

For landscape mode:

for Portrait mode:

I have also cropped the images to (Landscape:sizes="1024x748") and (Portrait:sizes="768x1004").

But the above are not working. Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue.
Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to follow all the links but none of them were working for me. I followed the following:
1. Created images of sizes (Landscape: 748x1024, Portrait: 768x1004).
2. Implemented the following code:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="748x1024" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/TestImage_1-screen-748x1024.png")"
        media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/TestImage_2-screen-768x1004.png")"
        media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) " />
```

Then I tested the changes in IPAD2 and it worked for me.

Thanks & Regards,
Santosh Kumar Patro

Answer (score 1):

For the third version of the iPad, "The new iPad", with the retina display, the dimensions are 2048x1536 (see [Apple's site](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/)). For the first iPad and the iPad 2, the dimensions are 1024x768 (again, see [Apple's site](http://www.apple.com/ipad/ipad-2/specs.html)). The dimensions you mentioned include the 20px status bar at the top. Here are the dimensions for some standard UI items:

- Navigation Bar and Tool Bars: 44 pixels
- Tab Bar: 49 pixels
- Status Bar: 20 pixels

I hope that helps. If not, give more detail about your results.